# Stop scrolling window element on keypress

Tags: javascript

I got a custom dropdown element and enabled scrolling on keypress, using `tabindex="-1"` on the elements combined with focusing the elements:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(`elem-${hasFocus.value}`)[0].focus();
```

Problem occurs when the keypress-scroll hits the top/bottom border. Then pressing the keys scrolls the window. The standard behavior is stopped by using `evt.preventDefault()`. But this also stops the "smooth" scroll behavior using `tabindex` (It keeps scrolling but just jumps to the list items). Is there a different way preventing the standard window scroll behavior?

I got no reproducable example but a git repo:
[Dropdown component](https://github.com/HaloElite/select-component/blob/main/select.vue)

The important method is `arrowNavigation`.

Comment: Surely you want to [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), rather than prevent default?

Comment: @DBS I also tried that. But the bahavior keeps being the same.

Comment: It sounds like you need to include a reproducing example of the problem in the question then, otherwise we have to make assumptions about your current approach.

Comment: @DBS I added the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understood well, but if what you want is to stop the event propagation to the window when using `evt.preventDefault()` in your handler, you can try `evt.stopPropagation()`

Comment: That's what I also tried. But it didn't stop the behavior. I guess scrolling up the parent element, when reaching borders of children, is kind of a standard behavior of the browser. That's why `preventDefault` prevents that. But it's still strange `stopPropagation` doesn't.

Comment: Can you show us some code so we can better understand the behavior you want and how you implemented it ?